# Where is app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Url\Rewrite function _getQueryString used?

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1

I am working on improving the documentation of magento functions and files, so developers can know where everything is used. Does anyone know where this is used or is this supposed to be extendable for third party code? For a popular CMS, the code is pretty barren of comments and the documentation for each function is barren too.

Comment: http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Core/Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite.html

Comment: @Fiasco_labs, thank you very much for trying to help, however I had already read that documentation, if it can even be called that. I am trying to figure out what part of the site the code executes on. It shouldn't be hard, but Magento has very little documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about `Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::_getQueryString` there are a few things to note.

1. It is protected so it can only be called from within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes,
2. It is depricated as of Mage 1.7 so it should not be called if possible,

So what you should use is `Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite_Request::_getQueryString` but again that is protected so only some classes can access this function.